# Infinite Load Page Phenomenon in Django Virtual Environments

Tags: django, google-chrome

I'm using MAC, and I had a problem developing django using virtual environments.

My development environment uses vscode to access the aws server, open the django virtual environment with 127.0.0.1:8000, and test the page using local(Mac) chrome.

I didn't have any particular issues before, but recently, page loading has suddenly slowed down and the page loading bar is running at infinity.

I changed the operating system to Windows and tried again, but there was no problem.

The issue only happens on my MacBook.

What should I do?

I emptied my MacBook's Chrome cache and reinstalled Chrome, but nothing improved.

I was wondering if it was a vscode problem, but my development environment is being developed using aws server, so it means that it is not a vscode problem to operate smoothly in Windows environment.